# Change Transparency Value of an Object in BGE with Keyboard

Tags: game-engine, objects, transparency

In the Blender Game Engine, I have a cube as a window and have set it's Z Transparency value to .200. I would like to add Keyboard Sensor where when I hit a specific key in-game, G for example, it would change the transparency value of the cube to 1.0, like a solid wall. I would also like this to work in reverse as well, where if I hit G a second time, the transparency value would return back to it's original .200. I'm sure there's a simple solution to this that I am overlooking but any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Transparency animation

- Go to first frame (1). Mouse cursor over Material/Transparency/Alpha <kbd>I</kbd>. The Alpha field will turn yellow.
  [image]
- go to last frame (21). The Alpha field should be green right now.
- enter 1.0
  [image]
- Mouse cursor over Material/Transparency/Alpha <kbd>I</kbd>.The Alpha field will turn yellow.

Go back to frame 1 again.

Your material action is prepared. You can play the material action the same way as any other action. Here is one option:

## Logic

Add an action actuator

- setup start frame (1)
- setup end frame (21)
- setup action name (MaterialAction)
- setup playback mode (Flipper)

[image]

Add a property

- "opaque"
- type: boolean

[image]

### logic to toggle opaque

```
Keyboard sensor -> AND -> Property Actuator Toggle "opaque"
```

### logic to play animation

```
Property Sensor Equal "opaque" True -> AND -> Action Actuator
```

[image]

I hope it helps